# List of mathematical portmanteaus

Tags: soft-question, big-list

Students (including myself) are always fascinated when they learn words like "clopen" set for closed and open in topology, or "club" set for closed and unbounded in set theory. I also learned recently that injective/surjective were a sort of portmanteau in French.

What other portmanteaus/ fun contractions are there in math? I'm having a hard time thinking of more than a couple.

Comment: "Cadlag" is an acronym from a French phrase, and is sometimes used when writing in English.

Comment: "iff" stands for if and only if.

Comment: Somewhat the opposite of joining words together is cleaving one in two: eg, Dirac's ["bra-ket" notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra–ket_notation) from "bracket".

Comment: "Quabla" is the quadratic nabla operator.

Comment: @KurtG.: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1183742/409), I mention John Conway's compulsion to follow "iff" with "thenn" ("then and only then"). Comments point out other Conwayisms: "whenn", "onne" (which was my own suggested answer to that question), "threee". The MathWorld ["Exactly One" entry](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExactlyOne.html) mentions "onee" (note the alternate spelling, which I would take to be the correct one), "twoo", and "threee".

Comment: poset for partially ordered sets

Comment: LOST: Language Of Set Theory, and an accurate description of the feelings of many beginners of this subject.... In Set Theory, "Club", "Diamond" and "Diamond$^+$" are axioms, consistent with but independent of ZFC that  are usually denoted by playing-card symbols . The axiom "Club" is a different thing from a club set.  K.Kunen uses c.u.b. for closed-unbounded.  And a result by Arnold Jensen about c.u.b. sets has been called "shooting a cub".

Comment: A nowhere-dense perfect subset of $[0,1]$ with positive Lebesgue measure is called a fat Cantor set.

Comment: "irrep" is an irreducible representation (of a group)

Comment: A [rep-tile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep-tile) is a shape that tiles itself.

Comment: Herewith, I solemnly make the proposal to call *irrep-tile* a shape that does not tile itself.

Comment: A [Gibonacci](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.03534.pdf) sequence is a generalized Fibonacci sequence.